# How to get Yammer File's list of topics?

Tags: yammer

I used yammer rest api “https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files/[:id].json" to get the file details, such as message's json contains "topics", but I found that the response json doesn't contains the file's topics information, 
So, I want to konw that is there any way to get file's topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not currently support retrieving the list of topics for uploaded files on Yammer as of August 2014. Sorry! The information is there, but there's no way to access it programmtically right now.